# Android old Layout for Button

Tags: android, layout, user-controls

I want to use an old layout for the Buttons in my app. All other Controls should look normal - only the Buttons should look like in Android 2.3. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3):

You have to create your own theme. It can look something like this:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo" >
        <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/MyButton </item>
</style>

<style name="MyButton" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button" />
```

Now every UI control will be holo, except the Button, since the we styled the button like the pre Holo Button by inheriting the old button styles.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own buttonSelector with the similar button shape of older version.